# Speech in PowerPoint (VBA)

Tags: vba, powerpoint, speech

I want to be able to make PowerPoint speak, say something.

I tried this code to make PP speak:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.Speech.Speak "Hello World"
End Sub
```

But the code doesn't work, it doesn't exists. What can I do, which is the right code?

It says:

> Compile Error Method or Data member not found.

Sorry for any error on my question.

Comment: That line seems correct. Why / how doesn't it work? What goes wrong? Post your full code.

Comment: I DON'T KNOW, that's why I'm here! This is the the full code. It says: Compile Error Method or Data member not found.

Comment: Acctualy the full code is:

Comment: Actually the full code is:
`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.Speech.Speak "Hello World"
End Sub`

Comment: Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that there's no Application.Speech property/method in the PPT object model.  Somewhere or other I've seen code that invokes Excel to do the lifting but here's an answer from John Wilson of PPT Alchemy that seems more direct:

There is a page on our site about talking message boxes
http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_speech.html

It could be easily modified to speak the text in a shape in Slide Show mode.

```
Sub speak(oshp As Shape)
  Dim strSpeak As String
  Dim SAPIObj As Object
  Set SAPIObj = CreateObject("SAPI.SPvoice")
  SAPIObj.Rate = -2
  If oshp.HasTextFrame Then
    If oshp.TextFrame.HasText Then
      strSpeak = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    End If
  End If

  SAPIObj.speak "<pitch middle='-15'>" & strSpeak

End Sub
```

If you don't need to pick up the text from a particular shape, a modification along these lines should do it:

```
Sub SayThisAloud(sText as String)

  Dim SAPIObj As Object
  Set SAPIObj = CreateObject("SAPI.SPvoice")
  SAPIObj.Rate = -2

  SAPIObj.speak "<pitch middle='-15'>" & sText

End Sub
```

Comment: Yep.  I tested it here again before posting, to make sure.

Comment: Is there a way to change the language?

Comment: Is there a way to change the language??

Comment: I don't know, but I'd start exploring here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723601(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: See new answer. It's a start.

Answer (score 0):

REgarding the MSDN page, it'll take some editing/modification to convert it to something a bit more useful.  For example, here's an example of how you can get a list of the voices available:

In the declarations section:

```
Private V As Object
Private T As Object
```

Then

```
Sub ListVoices()

    On Error GoTo EH

    Dim strVoice As String
    Dim SAPIObj As Object
    Set SAPIObj = CreateObject("SAPI.SPvoice")

    'Get each token in the collection returned by GetVoices
    For Each T In SAPIObj.GetVoices
        strVoice = T.GetDescription     'The token's name
        'List1.AddItem strVoice          'Add to listbox
        Debug.Print strVoice
    Next

Exit Sub

EH:
    If Err.Number Then ShowErrMsg
End Sub

Private Sub ShowErrMsg()

    ' Declare identifiers:
    Dim T As String

    T = "Desc: " & Err.Description & vbNewLine
    T = T & "Err #: " & Err.Number
    MsgBox T, vbExclamation, "Run-Time Error"
    End
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that code, but apparently there is just one Voice ("Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)")

Comment: I also have noticed that in Control Panel at the Speech Properties there is just on option for "Voice selection".

Comment: Ok, I tried to download a new language [**here**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-the-Speak-feature-with-Multilingual-TTS-e522a4f2-37cb-492b-be6a-8997d23dfe70#__toc252354033), I installed it but it didn't work, I also restarted my PC.

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I know about it.  Maybe someone else can jump in here with more experience?

Comment: Well, with some research and many tries I got to know how to install it, it is necessary to do some changes in Regestry, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me... maybe you can help me, link: https://superuser.com/questions/590779/how-to-install-more-voices-to-windows-speech